# What is this line about Rachel referring to?

Tags: history, imahot-matriarch-mothers

What is this line in the classic song [Mama Rochel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYtKqst5Tqg) talking about?

> But when nightfall came, Destiny betrayed,
>   The veil concealing another.
>   **Yet her sister's shame, not her shattered dreams,
>
>   Took hold of her heart and her senses.**
>   ([Lyrics](http://jewishlyrics.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none_24.html))

I'm wondering what the bolded part is talking about.

Comment: (Posted today because it's her yartzeit.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a reference to Rashi to [Bereishis 29:25](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8224#showrashi=true&v=25):

> מסר יעקב לרחל סימנים, וכשראתה רחל שמכניסין לו לאה אמרה עכשיו תכלם אחותי, עמדה ומסרה לה אותן סימנים
>
> Jacob had given signs to Rachel, but when she saw that they were bringing Leah, she (Rachel) said,“Now, my sister will be put to shame". So she readily transmitted those signs to her. - [from Meg. 13b]

Comment: So what is "took hold of her heart and her senses"?

Comment: @Scimonster, a poetic way of saying took priority.